# How to order by and select top 2 for each group

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table as below:

Logs:

```
ID | GroupCode | Date | Description
```

So ID is unique for each entry in the table. 
GroupCode is the way to group entries.

I would like to sort the table by GroupCode and Date DESC. Then look at the top 2 entries for each group to find out whether the description has changed from one to another in each group entry.

Description contains some key words such as "New", "Update" ,"delete" etc.

Complete Description is always differ from one to another but I should be able to just check the key words in latest 2 entries Description for each group and identify whether it has gone from New to Update or Update to New or Delete to New etc. If the key word has changed from one to another in the latest 2 entries Description for that group then my selection result should include that group and also the key word change. For example if the key word in the Description was New and gone to Update, the result should say as below:

```
GroupCode | Change
 x      "from New to Update"
```

Would this be possible to do with SQL query or a console application is required to analyse the entries?

Comment: What should happen if a description contains more than one of your keywords?   This is probably possible in SQL, but depending on the complexity of your keyword-matching rules, you might be better off using a language that allows REGEX.

Comment: The keywords are unique and each Description can and  should only contain one of those. but not multiple keywords.

Comment: `cross apply` to `select top (2)`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. First create a subquery to get top 2 entries for each group using [ROW_NUMBER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx). Just partition by GroupName, sort by Date and take the rows with `rownumbercolumn in (1,2)`

Then you can compare current row with a previous one using [LAG](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx) function to compose the Change column. Just make a simple check to make sure you don't compare rows from different groups.

```
if exists(select * from [sys].[tables] where [name]='Logs' )
    drop table [Logs]

go

create table [Logs](
[Id] int identity not null primary key,
[GroupCode] varchar(50) not null,
[Date] date not null,
[Description] varchar(100) not null
)

insert [Logs]([GroupCode], [Date], [Description]) values('Group1', '2016-05-01', 'New')
insert [Logs]([GroupCode], [Date], [Description]) values('Group1', '2016-05-03', 'Update')
insert [Logs]([GroupCode], [Date], [Description]) values('Group1', '2016-05-04', 'Update')
insert [Logs]([GroupCode], [Date], [Description]) values('Group1', '2016-05-05', 'Delete')


insert [Logs]([GroupCode], [Date], [Description]) values('Group2', '2016-05-06', 'New')
insert [Logs]([GroupCode], [Date], [Description]) values('Group2', '2016-05-08', 'Update')
insert [Logs]([GroupCode], [Date], [Description]) values('Group2', '2016-05-15', 'Delete')
insert [Logs]([GroupCode], [Date], [Description]) values('Group2', '2016-05-20', 'New')


insert [Logs]([GroupCode], [Date], [Description]) values('Group3', '2016-05-21', 'New')
insert [Logs]([GroupCode], [Date], [Description]) values('Group3', '2016-06-03', 'Update')
insert [Logs]([GroupCode], [Date], [Description]) values('Group3', '2016-06-04', 'Update')
insert [Logs]([GroupCode], [Date], [Description]) values('Group3', '2016-06-05', 'Update')


select [GroupCode], [Change] from
(select *, 
case when LAG([Description]) OVER (ORDER BY [GroupCode] ASC, [Date] asc) = [Description] then 'No Change Visible' else
'From ' + LAG([Description]) OVER (ORDER BY [GroupCode] ASC, [Date] asc) + ' to ' + [Description] end [Change] from
(select [GroupCode], [Date], [Description], row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY [GroupCode] ORDER BY [Date] DESC) AS RowNumber
from Logs) Q1 -- Q1 query takes top 2 by date DESC for each group
where RowNumber in (1,2)) Q2 -- Q2 composes the change column by taking prev row value
where RowNumber = 1 -- here we just take last row fpr each group
```

The result is

```
GroupCode    Description
Group1       From Update to Delete
Group2       From Delete to New
Group3       No Change Visible
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could write some script

Comment: @akd was it helpful? is there anything else I can help you with?